# Why can I not boot from the hard disk?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, hard-drive

I installed 12.04 from a USB stick (alternate image, 64-bit).  If I boot off the USB, and select the option to boot from the hard disk, then it all works fine.

But if I remove the USB stick and attempt to boot off the hard drive, then the computer doesn't boot.  Instead, it displays the following message after the BIOS POST:

```
ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.
```

The computer is an Acer Aspire X1470.

Anyone know what I must do to get it to boot from the hard disk?

---

Update:  I'm not sure what this means:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: This GPT partition label has no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible!.
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Comment: Why not try and reinstall GRUB once more? Refer to this http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-using-ubuntu/

Comment: The installer wrote the boot loader on usb, that make the error.Please keep your eyes wide open when you run installer especially when it shows the drive for installation.

Comment: beeju:  I chose the option to upgrade my 11.10 system to 12.04.  I didn't tell it where to install.

Comment: harisibrahimkv:  when I try that post I get the following:  "WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted."

Comment: What are the reasons for a GPT partition? UEFI BIOS? If not, did you create a separate boot partition?

Comment: I don't even know what GPT partition means.  Or what UEFI means.  When I installed 11.10, I simply chose the option "use the whole disk".  This computer came with Windows, but I never booted into Windows even once.  I completely overwrote it with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Boot with your USB.  Download and execute this:

Try to repair the boot with this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Nice looking tool!  I clicked on "recommended repair" but it didn't fix the problem, it still fails to find a boot disk when I start the computer.  It did give a lot of information:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/964989/

Comment: In this case try to install grub with this command: sudo grub-install /dev/sda

Where /dev/sda is your hard drive. (it can also be sa1 etc.)   If this will not work you have to reinstall the system and take take care at the moment the system ask you where will you boot from (most of the time you answer is / ).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the Boot-Repair log, you have a **GPT disk, an EFI partition, and your BIOS is setup in non-EFI mode.**

3 solutions:

1. **If your BIOS allows it**, setup your BIOS in EFI mode, and make it boot on your sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file.
2. **As suggested by Boot-Repair**, via gParted convert your sda1 partition into a BOOT-bios partition (>1Mo, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag), then run Boot-Repair again.
3. **Via Gparted convert your disk into a non-GPT disk** (this will format your disk), then reinstall Ubuntu.